# Build MethodCallExpression for DateTime as string for DataTables Api table search

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatables, expression

I have expression builder for DataTables Api page search which should parse DateTime? to string and check whether it contains value i.e. "11/" or "5"

```
private static List<Expression> GetDateTimeExpression(List<Expression> expressionList, IDataQuery queryAdapter, PropertyInfo property, ParameterExpression parameter)
{
    var searchValue = queryAdapter.SearchObject.Value;
    
    var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property.Name);
    var memberExpValue = Expression.Property(memberExpression, "Value");
    
    var methodInfo = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToString", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var toStringExp = Expression.Call(memberExpValue, methodInfo, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string))); // Issue here as Constant value is always inserted

    var methodInfo2 = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(toStringExp, methodInfo2, Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(string)));

    expressionList.Add(methodCallExpression);

    return expressionList;
}
```

Current result:
p.DateCreated.Value.ToString(**null**).Contains("1") - which fails on .ToString(null) as null is not a valid in Linq Expression

Instead I should get:
p.DateCreated.Value.**ToString()**.Contains("1")

Is there any way how to achieve this?

Comment: Get from this my answer [EnsureString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72813230/10646316) function. It uses `Convert.ToString` which is convertible to the SQL if it is needed.

Comment: Your answer is: `var toStringExp = Expression.Call(memberExpValue, nameof(string.ToString), Type.EmptyTypes);`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that did the trick! Thank you very much