# EF Core expression tree CAST equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I'm trying to search for a string-equivalent value (which user inputs as HTTP request query parameter) in my SQL database on non-string columns (ie. `bool`, `int`, `decimal`, `datetime`, etc....). In order to have a generic method that would perform that task, I am writing my query using EF Core Linq expression trees.

Basically, what I would like to achieve in SQL query equivalent would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [joint].[UploadedFile] AS [u]
WHERE 
    (CAST([u].[ID] AS varchar) LIKE N'%.pdf%') 
    OR (CAST([u].[Size] AS varchar) LIKE N'%.pdf%')
    OR (CAST([u].[IsValid] AS varchar) LIKE N'%.pdf%')
    OR (CAST([u].[DateOfUpload] AS varchar) LIKE N'%.pdf%') 
    OR ([u].[FileName] LIKE N'%.pdf%') OR ([u].[Type] LIKE N'%.pdf%');
```

where `ID` is of type `int`, `Size` is of type `decimal`, `IsValid` is of type `bool`, `DateOfUpload` is of type `datetime` and `FileName` is of type `string` (`nvarchar(500)`, to be exact).

Is it possible to achieve SQL query as written above using EF Core linq expression trees?

I have tried writing the following LINQ expression for non-string properties:

```
contains_expression = Expression.Call(
                        Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name), typeof(string)),
                        contains_method, 
                        Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string))
                    );
```

However, when I try to run it I get the following exception message:

> No coercion operator is defined between types '' and 'System.String'

Comment: You shouldn't do this. It's very bad for performance to convert database columns in predicates (see *sargable*). Also, what's the use? An `int`, etc. will *never* match  `N'%.pdf%'`.

Comment: The idea behind query would be to allow user to insert a string value, and then to perform "quick search" on all table fields that contain following string value. So the user can input a "pure" string value (ie. 'pdf'), a part of datetime value (ie. '2022-12'), a part that is contained in int value (ie. 101 would match 101, 2101, 41015, …) and so on

Comment: Check [EnsureString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72813230/10646316) from my answer.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thank you for your comment. I have tried and can confirm that your solution works in my case. Thanks.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: I am using EF Core 7.0 with MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `Expression.Convert` as implementing a type cast, so your `Expression` is trying to do e.g. `(string)12`, which is an error. There is no cast from `int` to `string`. Instead you can call `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
var memberExpr = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name),
                                    typeof(Object)
                 );
var stringTypeExpr = Expression.Constant(typeof(string), typeof(Type));
var convFieldExpr = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(typeof(Convert),
                                                       "ChangeType",
                                                       Type.EmptyTypes,
                                                       memberExpr,
                                                       stringTypeExpr
                                       ),
                                       typeof(string)
                    );
var contains_expression = Expression.Call(convFieldExpr,
                                          contains_method,
                                          Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string))
                          );
```

Comment: I have tried your proposed solution, but I end up getting the following error: 
`The LINQ expression 'DbSet<UploadedFile>().Where(u => u.FileName.Contains(".pdf") || ((string)Convert.ChangeType( value: (object)u.ID, conversionType: (Type)System.String)).Contains(".pdf"))...' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

Comment: @GoranPetrović You need to try a literal test lambda method to see what is supported by your LINQ provider.